In R2JAGS, how can I code an interaction between two variables within a survival model?
My model has three independent variables: snow (a categorical variable of whether or not snow was present, which is arranged as a matrix by time and individual), sex (also categorical), and HFL (a scaled continuous morphological measure which did not change over time). I have not had any issues coding the basic additive model, which is below.
# Model
# Known-fate survival model
# Includes three covariate: Sex, male (0) or female (1), HFL, and snow presence

model {
  
  # Priors and constraints
  for(i in 1:nind){
    for(t in (f[i]+1):n.occs[i]){
      logit(phi[i,t]) <- int + sex.eff * sex[i] + HFL.eff * HFL[i] + snow.eff * snow[i,t] + ind.eff[i]
    } #t
  } #i
  
  
  # Prior for mean survival
  mean.phi ~ dunif(0, 1)
  mean.annual <- mean.phi ^ 52
  int <- log(mean.phi/(1-mean.phi))
  
  # Prior for IVs
  sex.eff ~ dnorm(0, 0.001)
  HFL.eff ~ dnorm(0, 0.001)
  snow.eff ~ dnorm(0, 0.001)
  
  #  SD of individual variation
  tau.phi <- 1/(sigma.phi ^ 2)
  sigma.phi ~ dunif(0, 50)
  
  for(i in 1:nind){
    ind.eff[i] ~ dnorm(0, tau.phi)
  }
  
  
  #  Don't change below this point
  # Likelihood
  for(i in 1:nind){
    mu[i,f[i]] <- 1
    for(t in (f[i]+1):n.occs[i]){
      mu[i,t] <- phi[i,t] * y[i,t-1]
      y[i,t] ~ dbern(phi[i,t])
    } #t
  } #i
  
}

Code used to run model:
library(R2jags)
library(mcmcplots)
library(bayesplot) # diagnostics

#  Load module 
load.module("glm")
jags.data <- list(y = y, # y is survival data matrix
                  nind = nind, 
                  f = f, 
                  n.occs = n.occs,
                  sex = sex,
                  HFL = HFL,
                  snow = snow
)

#  Define initial values for parameters as a function
inits <- function(){
  list(mean.phi = runif(1, 0, 1),
       sigma.phi = runif(1, 0, 5))
}

#  Define parameters to monitor
parameters <- c("mean.phi",
                "sigma.phi", 
                "int",
                "mean.annual", "sex.eff", "HFL.eff", "snow.eff")

#  Call it in parallel
start.time <- Sys.time()

out <- jags.parallel( # jags or jags.parallel
  dat= jags.data,
  inits = inits, # or no inits: inits = NULL,
  parameters.to.save = parameters,
  
  
  model.file = "models/kf.sex-hfl-snow.re.txt", # 
  
  n.thin = 3,
  n.chains = 3,
  n.burnin = 10000, 
  n.iter = 100000)

end.time <- Sys.time();(time.taken <-end.time-start.time)

out

# diagnostics
mcmc_samples <- as.mcmc(out)
mcmc_trace(mcmc_samples, pars = c("HFL.eff", "snow.eff", "sex.eff", "mean.phi", "int"))
mcmc_dens(mcmc_samples, pars = c("HFL.eff", "snow.eff", "sex.eff", "mean.phi", "int"))

I now would like to make a model with an interaction between HFL and snow. However, I have had several false starts that have simply given me errors, and I am not sure how to proceed in order to code this model. The examples of coding interactions that I have been able to find online (1, 2) have not been complex enough to help me figure out what to do.
EDIT: I tried something very simple with this:
# Known-fate survival model
# Interaction between HFL (scaled continuous) and snow (categorical)

model {
  
  # Priors and constraints
  for(i in 1:nind){
    for(t in (f[i]+1):n.occs[i]){
      logit(phi[i,t]) <- int + sex.eff * sex[i] + HFL.eff * HFL[i] + snow.eff * snow[i,t] + ind.eff[i] + HFL.snow * HFL[i] * snow[i,t]
    } #t
  } #i
  
  
  # Prior for mean survival
  mean.phi ~ dunif(0, 1)
  mean.annual <- mean.phi ^ 52
  int <- log(mean.phi/(1-mean.phi))
  
  # Prior for IVs
  sex.eff ~ dnorm(0, 0.001)
  HFL.eff ~ dnorm(0, 0.001)
  snow.eff ~ dnorm(0, 0.001)
  HFL.snow ~ dnorm(0, 0.001)
  
  #  SD of individual variation
  tau.phi <- 1/(sigma.phi ^ 2)
  sigma.phi ~ dunif(0, 50)
  
  for(i in 1:nind){
    ind.eff[i] ~ dnorm(0, tau.phi)
  }
  
  
  #  Don't change below this point
  # Likelihood
  for(i in 1:nind){
    mu[i,f[i]] <- 1
    for(t in (f[i]+1):n.occs[i]){
      mu[i,t] <- phi[i,t] * y[i,t-1]
      y[i,t] ~ dbern(phi[i,t])
    } #t
  } #i
  
}

And it worked? I got an output that appeared to have converged, but now I'm unsure if what I did was correct, as well as how to interpret it. Any advice would be welcome.
Inference for Bugs model at "models/kf.sex-hfl-int-snow.re.txt", fit using jags,
 3 chains, each with 1e+05 iterations (first 10000 discarded), n.thin = 3
 n.sims = 90000 iterations saved. Running time = secs
            mu.vect sd.vect    2.5%     25%     50%     75%   97.5%  Rhat n.eff
HFL.eff       0.105   0.277  -0.444  -0.076   0.105   0.287   0.650 1.001 90000
HFL.snow      0.138   0.321  -0.489  -0.076   0.138   0.349   0.779 1.001 16000
int           3.085   0.339   2.422   2.860   3.082   3.307   3.759 1.001  4300
mean.annual   0.113   0.077   0.012   0.055   0.097   0.154   0.302 1.001  5200
mean.phi      0.954   0.015   0.918   0.946   0.956   0.965   0.977 1.001  5200
sex.eff       0.569   0.447  -0.277   0.267   0.557   0.856   1.488 1.002  3400
sigma.phi     1.266   0.371   0.536   1.028   1.261   1.504   2.009 1.019   840
snow.eff     -0.061   0.343  -0.730  -0.292  -0.062   0.168   0.619 1.001 20000
deviance    395.217  16.937 364.765 383.331 394.246 405.903 431.869 1.002  1800

